# view everyone's calendar entries

Tags: calendar

In our company we need a calendar on the default sharepoint page (or homepage) where every user can synchronise it with MS-Outlook. Ok, thats not the problem.

But what we also need is if a user connects to the default-website or to his MS-Outlook and views the calendar, he should see ALL user entries in there 
without selecting appropriate users.

Until now i could view entries of other users but i have to select them repeatedly every time i view the calendar.

That means we need a calendar where everyone (who is authorized) could view everyone's entries therefore it is not necessery to select single users. And add his own entry if he want to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe syncing your events to a single, company-wide SharePoint calendar would be the difficult part. If you have that part figured out, the rest is simple.

Each user will need to navigate to the SharePoint calendar in their web browser and click the "Actions" menu > "Connect to Outlook".

See also this link for step-by-step instructions:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-update-a-sharepoint-calendar-HA010081987.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer your looking for:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=58

Basically, create a list, and set precisions on the list for everyone to view and edit items.  Then the calendar which is reading from the list will show up with everyone's edits.